# Have a Value continue to increase while another loop is running in matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, switch-statement, monitoring, nested-loops

I have three operations. Each operation is in a loop and has a `flag` value that decreases when the operation is running. While the operation is running, any other operation with the `flag` value reaching the maximum threshold should interrupt it and run instead (has the highest priority). The `flag` value changes according to a differential equation against time.

- I want each operation's `flag` value to increase when another operation is running, and signal the system to switch to it when the `flag` value reaches the maximum threshold.
- The `flag` value of each operation increases and decreases according to a specific differential equation that changes with time when the operation is running.

All operations are currently in one file, looped in a `Switch case` statement. The current code is :

```
while 1
  [value, index]=max(flag);
  switch index
      case 1
          operation1
          ...
          ...
          flag = [x y z]
      case 2
          operation2
          ...
          ...
          flag = [x y z]
      case 3
          operation3
          ...
          ...
          flag = [x y z]
    end
end
```

Any ideas ? If you need me to explain a bit better then please do tell me.

Comment: What do you mean by operation?  Are you trying to setup multiple concurrent processes?

Comment: @slayton An operation is just a loop .. bunch of differential equations. Well, if I want to achieve what I posted I think they should be concurrent ?? I don't know, hence why I posted here for some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches here

1. Each time an operation is run, the others should gain some weight, the next time an operation is selected the one with the highest weight is chosen.
2. Each millisecond an operation is run, the others should gain some weight, the next time an operation is selected the one with the highest weight is chosen.
3. Each millisecond an operation is run, the others should gain some weight. As soon as an operation loses its highest flag status it should be interrupted.

Each requires a different solution

---

Here are some suggested solutions, for the corresponding problems:

1. Fairly trivial, just increase the flag of all operations by 1 everytime you run an operation, or alternately reduce the flag of this operation by 1.
2. Measure the time that it took to complete the operation (perhaps with `tic` and `toc`), increase the flag of all other operations with this value.
3. Give the flag as input to the operation, and inside the operation stop when the elapsed time lets this operation exceed one other flag. Note that without adjustment this means that you basically try to alternate operations by the millisecond.

Comment: I like the number one. However, the flag value is the output of a differential equation, and hence decreases according to a differential equation as well. So the subtraction should be a differential equation rather than just one, and hence can be tedious for 3 operations or more in the future, wouldn't it ? --- I updated the question with the extra detail. Do you think this is feasible ?

Comment: @NLed I don't know how you imagine substracting a differential equation, but for scalars it should be fine. Note that from this code it is not a problem if the flag is negative.

Comment: Two differential equations, one causes the flag to increase when the operation is stopped, the other causes the flag to decrease when the operation is running.